# media queries working on one site but not another

Tags: css, media-queries

I am working on two different responsive websites (both work in progress and one is taken from lynda.com just for practice). This first one I did works fine as far as I can tell. 
The HTML is [HERE](http://kimwilddesigns.com/index_new.htm) and CSS is [HERE](http://kimwilddesigns.com/css/kw_styles-responsive2.css).

Then I started to work on this one, created the same css as above but the media query targeting @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) is not loading for some reason. 
HTML is [HERE](http://kimwilddesigns.com/TrailGuide_website/TrailGuide_website-class/index_fluid.html) and CSS is [HERE](http://kimwilddesigns.com/TrailGuide_website/TrailGuide_website-class/css/trail-fluid_styles.css).
I've spent hours trying to figure out why and I'm lost. I don't any differences between the two, yet one is working and one isn't. Any suggestions you have would be much appreciated!

I'm just testing them in a browser right now.

Thank You!

Comment: I just noticed that your reset.css is below your site CSS. You may want to reverse them.

Comment: Hi - Thanks, but that has no effect on the media queries problem.

Comment: I knew it wouldn't. Just making a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is one site has a "meta...viewport..." in its HTML, while in the other site that statement is commented out.

In the site with no "meta...viewport..." the Media Queries are actually testing against the dimensions of the unconstrained "viewport" rather than the "screen" (an oversimplification is "devices sometimes lie"). On the other hand in the site with "meta...viewport...width=device-width" the "viewport" width is forced down to be the same as the "screen" width before the Media Queries test it, so you get different answers (especially on smaller devices).

(Depending on what devices you're targeting, you may need to dive down into thoroughly understanding a "viewport". There are good reasons for the way a "viewport" behaves; please don't misinterpret my sarcastic "devices sometimes lie" to mean "viewports are a bad idea".)